# Расчёт суммы в Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Я пытаюсь посчитать сумму чисел во 2-ой колонке с помощью макроса Excel:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код макроса:

```
Sub SumMacro()
    Call Sum_Demo
End Sub

Public Sub Sum_Demo()
    Dim myRange
    Dim Results

    myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2", "B11")
    Results = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange)
    Range("C2") = Results
End Sub
```

Но почему-то в результате выполнения макроса в ячейке С2 выводится только 0:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предполагаю, что это из-за формата ячеек (*General*). Но как это исправить (чтобы вид ячеек во втором столбце не изменился)?

Comment: Проверил (изменив последнюю строку на `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2") = Results`) - всё нормально... а у Вас в колонке В (исходных данных) случайно не текст? а десятичный разделитель часом не запятая?

Comment: @Akina нет, тоже General. При изменении формата в ячейке C2 на Number вывело 0,00. А где можно узнать/изменить десятичный разделитель?

Comment: *При изменении формата в ячейке C2 на Number вывело 0,00.* Вот именно так, с запятой? тогда замените в колонке B точки на запятые... должно помочь.

Comment: @Akina, да, после замены запятой на точку сумма выводится верно. А без этой замены средствами макроса это можно как-либо сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хранить данные на листах нужно в их родных форматах, не будет дополнительной головной боли. Но бывают случаи, когда данные получают из сторонних программ и там может быть всякое...

В ячейках не числа - там текст - числа располагаются в правой части ячейки. Да и разделитель в русской локали обычно запятая.

Обращение к объектам листа и работа функциями листа - медленные, предпочтительнее всю обработку производить в памяти, обращаясь к листу только для получения и выгрузки данных.

```
Sub Sum_Demo2()
Dim a()
Dim dRes As Double
Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        a = .Range("B2:B11").Value ' значения в массив

        ' суммируем в цикле с заменой разделителя
        For i = 1 To UBound(a)
            If a(i, 1) <> Empty Then
                dRes = dRes + Replace(a(i, 1), ".", ",")
            End If
        Next i

        .Range("C2").Value = dRes
    End With
End Sub
======================
```

Функцию листа использовать нежелательно, но можно, попутно изменив данные на листе. Перед суммированием меняем формат ячеек для правильного визуального отображения чисел (это не обязательно) и меняем разделитель. С заменой разделителя небольшой фокус: так как в *VBA* разделителем целой и дробной части является точка (не запятая!), то производим замену точки на точку.

```
Sub Sum_Demo()
Dim myRange As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set myRange = .Range("B2:B11") ' присваиваем переменной диапазон
        myRange.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00" ' меняем формат
        myRange.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart ' меняем разделитель

        .Range("C2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange.Value) ' суммируем
    End With

    Set myRange = Nothing ' освобождаем память
End Sub
```